# Where can one find the Powerpoint 365 Animation Pane for an audio object?

Tags: microsoft-365

Though [Apply multiple animation effects to one object](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-multiple-animation-effects-to-one-object-9bb7b925-ab0f-47d4-bc11-85d939194bed) "Microsoft 365 support" "PowerPoint" says:

[image: Open the Animation Pane: 1. Select the object on the slide that you want to animate. 2. On the Animations tab, click Animation Pane.]

Here on [Powerpoint 365](https://www.microsoft365.com/launch/powerpoint), when I select an object:

[image: image selected, showing resize handles]

there's no such button:

[image: visual effect types, timing, and order options]

So, where can one find the Powerpoint 365 Animation Pane?

Note:

[Sound Across Specific Slides in PowerPoint 365 for Windows](https://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/multimedia/365/sound-across-specific-slide.html) corroborates the above procedure, and I have performed its steps 1-4, of which 4 here gives:

[image: audio options and audio styles menus]

Comment: The referred help article clearly states that it's about desktop apps: "In the PowerPoint desktop apps, you can apply multiple animation effects to a single string of text or an object, such as a picture, shape, or SmartArt graphic." You need to look at the help for for the web apps.

Comment: Start by studying [Create a presentation in PowerPoint for the web](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-presentation-in-powerpoint-for-the-web-21360025-7eef-4173-9d7c-08281d55f64a)

Comment: I voted to reopen, since "there is no Powerpoint 365 Animation Pane" would be a valid answer and it makes sense to look for features available in the desktop edition.